# How to share cookies across ports/domains with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

I have two node.js (express) apps running on two different ports. One is running on `localhost:3000` and the other is running at `localhost:4000`. The app on port `3000` has the following cookie configuration:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser())

app.use(express.session({
    key: settings.session.key,
    secret: settings.session.secret,
    cookie: settings.session.cookie,
    fingerprint: function () { return '' },
    store: new MemoryStore()
}))
```

And the other app (on port `4000`) has:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser())

app.use(express.session({
    key: settings.session.key,
    secret: settings.session.secret,
    cookie: settings.session.cookie,
    fingerprint: function() { return ''  },
    store: new MongoSessionStore({ db: db })
}))
```

They are both using the same session configuration object (only difference is one is being stored in MongoDB while the other is in-memory.

I set a cookie like so on `localhost:3000`:

```
res.cookie('mycookie', 'bar', { domain: 'localhost:4000' })
```

And I then POST (with jquery.ajax) to a route on `localhost:4000`, and the cookie `mycookie` is not present.

Note: I have CORS setup on `localhost:4000` to accept the origin `localhost:3000`, and when I post with Jquery I use `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }`.

So my question is, how to configure the apps correctly to set cookies to one another? :)

Comment: What happens if you use the same mongo session store for both sites?

Comment: @JoshC. it results in shared sessions between the two apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you share your session store between both apps.

Edit: Just to clarify you can't set cookies from one domain to another. So **domainA** can't set a cookie for **domainB** - you must get **domainB** to set the cookie (eg. by visiting **domainB**). Using your current config you should be able to read the cookies as expected.

Originally, I thought you wanted to share state between two apps via cookies which is why I suggested sharing the session store between the apps.

Comment: You can actually. what about if you're using httpOnly?